# Where to ARC Welder extrude "minidump file(.dmp)"?

Tags: google-chrome

Im debugging Android app(emulating by ARC welder) on Chromebook, and often get `"plugin crashed: captured minidump"` message.

But I dont know where to extrude the "minidump".

https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/packages/crash-reporting/debugging-a-minidump
I saw this link, however  cant find "minidumpfile(foo.dmp)".
In my Chromebook, only those binary files in directory(/usr/bin/).

```
core2md, minidump-2-core, minidump_upload, minidump_dump, minidump_stackwalk
```

Because I cant find dumpfile, cant extrude corefile.
What am I missing? What should I do?

How do you debug ARC minidump?